# Database referencing columns from tables?

Tags: mysql

I am sure what I am trying to do is basic practise, but I can't find the solution for this. I searched about foreign keys but I don't think this is what I need here.

My desired behaviour: I have an app which has a "locations" tab and a "contact" tab. This data will be pulled from a database. The information will be filled in in a cms. There are two things a user can choose for the contact: Choose existing Contact from location(which pulls the name + mail) or create a new one. In my file, I am then pulling the data from my contact table and just display the rows in select elements.(see below for a short example).

So in my contact table I need to have two things: Either a reference to the name + mail from my location table or a new record(custom mail + name)

I have two tables:

```
+-------------------+
| LOCATION          |
+-------------------+
| primary           |
| name              |
| zip               |
| mail              |
| ...               |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
| CONTACT           |
+-------------------+
| primary           |
| (lid)             |
| name              |
| mail              |
+-------------------+
```

The relationship between location and contact is a one to one/none relationship. So there can be locations without a contact.

The contact can be two things: a reference to a location(which then pulls name + mail from there), so that when a user updates a location, the contact will automatically update, or create a "custom" contact.

Ex:

User creates location with: name "Test" mail "test@mail.com"

User selects "Test" for the creation of a new contact which: pulls "Test" and "test@mail.com" as name and mail from location table(also updates it when the location is updated)

User creates contact with: name "Custom" mail "custom@mail.com"

I then have a contact form, which pulls in the data from the contact table, so that it then displays:

```
<select>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Custom</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this? I know the solution, if I would just need one of the examples. Creating a table where a user can insert custom data, for example, is easy practise. But how can I combine a "custom" and a "relational" functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to populate drop down with values from the database?, what language are you using?

Comment: I am using php, but populating the values from a database is not the problem. The problem is the combination in a table of 1) custom data filled in by the user, and 2) data referencing to another table.

Comment: I cant see a common field in both tables that could be used for referencing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider normalising the database so that contacts are stored in the contacts table and a reference to the contact record in held in the location table.

```
+-------------------+
| LOCATION          |
+-------------------+
| id                |
| contact_id        |
| zip               |
| ...               |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
| CONTACT           |
+-------------------+
| id                |
| name              |
| mail              |
+-------------------+
```

When amending a location, If the user selects an existing contact, you can store the id in contact_id.  If they are adding a new one, then have the application first save the new contact and then use this newly created contact's id

Comment: Hey, I don't know exactly how to display this in my post, but the relationship between location and contact is a one to one/none relationship. So there can be locations without a contact.

Comment: so the same contact cannot be for more than one location?

Comment: you can allow contact_id in location to have a null value, indicating that there is no corresponding contact record

Comment: Ahhh I've got it... I will just use another value which says "display: TRUE/FALSE" in my contact table... Then it works perfectly fine in combination with your solution